# Нужно ли всегда инициализировать объект, если он потом используется в условии?

Tags: c++

Отлавливал баг в программе пару часов, пока не поставил после некоторых строчек вывод сообщений, чтобы узнать в какой строчке выполнялся код, а на какой остановился. До этого как-то не было проблем с этим или я не использовал, может быть. Так вот, что находится в объекте, если его использовать без инициализации в if(object)? Все что угодно? То есть постоянно нужно инициализировать объект хотя бы NULL, если он используется до инициализации? И проверку на NULL не нужно же делать, то есть if(object) вместо if(object != NULL), главное перед этим инициализировать?